# Sprockets::FileOutsidePaths in Posts#index where application.css.scss is no longer under a load path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, sprockets

So I decided to clone my repo from github and came up with this error. I'm not exactly sure how this came about when the original still works. Thank you everyone who is able to help.

```
<head>
```

```html
Extracted source (around line #5):
3  <head>
4   <title>Yarp</title>
5    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
6    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
7    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8  </head>
```

My application.index.erb

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Yarp</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>


  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>

 <div class="container">
  <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
   <div id="flash" class="flash-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
  <% end %>

  <%= yield %>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Heres my Gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.2'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.5.2'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.10.0'
gem 'auto_html', '~> 1.6.4'
# Design
gem 'font-awesome-rails', '~> 4.4.0.0'
gem 'bourbon', '~> 4.2.3'
gem 'neat', '~> 1.7.2'
gem 'refills', '~> 0.1.0'
gem 'normalize-rails', '~> 3.0.3'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running `bundle exec rake tmp:clear` helped me.

[Source.](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/issues/96)

Comment: Wow, Thank You! I had tried a rake reset, and then a bundle update, but didn't know I could do a bundle rake temp clear. I'll need to find and read more on rake commands. Thank you again.